# On ubuntu touch device, How to launch a console app in libertine?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have installed desktop app named "obfsprosy" in libertine container,
this app is a console app without things about desktop,so I can't find it's icon from scope,
and How to launch it?
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Try to digit `obfsproxy` on terminal.

Comment: Also, you may want to explore the option of creating a .desktop file in .local/share/aplications.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to install a terminal emulator in the container such as `terminator` or `gnome-terminal`, and then launch the application directly from that terminal. To install the terminal emulator:

```
$ libertine-container-manager --id your-container --package terminator
```

where `your-container` is the id of your container. Then just tap the "Terminal" icon in the Desktop Apps scope to start it and type the name of the command you want to run (`obfsproxy`).

As one of the comments mentioned, you could create a .desktop file in the container's `.local/share/applications` which launches the terminal app within the emulator when you tap its icon. You can find the bind-mounts and home data for your container in `/home/phablet/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/your-container` (let's call this `$CONTAINER_HOME`). You'll want a file like `$CONTAINER_HOME/.local/share/applications/obfsproxy.desktop`* which might look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=obfsproxy
Comment=Obfuscate the fact that your traffic is generated by OpenVPN
Exec=terminator --execute obfsproxy --log-file=obfsproxy.log --log-min-severity=info obfs2 --shared-secret=<some-random-key> socks 127.0.0.1:10194
Icon=
Type=Application
Categories=System;
```

Of course, you can change the command after `terminator --execute` to do anything.

* There may currently be a bug preventing the scope from finding applications in this directory. If your .desktop file does not show up in the results, you can move it to `/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/your-container/rootfs/usr/share/applications/`.

*Note: Although there was work being done to launch Terminal apps directly through the Scope, that work is on hiatus as some redesign is being completed.*

Comment: Can you give a detailed example how to launch the application? I am not used to those containers and I never created .desktop files. Do I need to log in to the container? How is it done?